# Constantly Requesting and Collecting Data for a Certain Period of Time

Tags: c#, loops, datetime, time, constants

I need to retrieve data as fast as possible continually for X number of minutes by sending a command and then reading the result . I am unsure if the following code works efficiently or for the purpose of constant retrieval:

```
DateTime utcStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        while (DateTime.UtcNow <= (utcStartTime.AddSeconds(recordTime)))                       //Run the read-write function for approximately the time specified
        {
            try
            {

                Write("Write.Request");                                 //Requests the data
                Pmeas = Read();                                         //Reads the returned string. String = "ReadError" if no result is found.
                                                                        //Note that the following error checker doesn't effect the speed of data collection at a millisecond level (already checked), and is therefore not the cause of any delay.
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Pmeas))
                {
                    Pmeas = "ReadError";                                //Necessary due to an apparent overwrite caused by the read function - Tells the later output (outside of while loop) that Pmeas experienced a read error
                    DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;                 //Get the current time in UTC seconds (may need correcting).
                    pArray[i] = (Pmeas + "\t" + utcTime.ToString("%d") + Environment.NewLine);    //Appends the Pmeas of each instance to a string array with a timestamp
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    pArray[i] = (Pmeas + "\t" + utcTime.ToString("%d") + Environment.NewLine);    //Appends the Pmeas of each instance to a string array with a timestamp
                }
                Pmeas = "ReadError";                                    //Reset Pmeas to prove in file that Pmeas experienced a read error
            }
            catch (Exception f)                                         //Catch an exception if try fails
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", f);
            }
            i++;                                            //let i grow so that the array can also grow, plus have a variable already available for being having the string being written into a file (not part of question or code-in-question).
        }
```

Note that all variable such as i, Pmeas, and pArray are all predefined before the loop (to prevent errors) and the UTC should be in seconds (not sure of the current syntax; with decimal accuracy). As I said, I am looking for a method that constantly collects data from another source using the Read and Write functions given above, continually doing this without delay for a set period of time. My simple question is, ***is this the right way to collect the data or is there a better and/or more efficient way?***

All input on the code is welcome, even if it doesn't answer the question in full.

Comment: How long do the `Write` and `Read` actually take?  Is the code posted above actually causing quantifiable speed issues - eg if those methods are an order of magnitude slower (for example) than the code you've got wrapped around them, I wouldn't worry about it...

Comment: The current code above, (which was originally in a for loop) has a delay of 17 milliseconds. We're trying to get it down to at least half that, but we still require the timestamp for each data point taken.

Comment: @Midimistro If you want to reach that goal you need to know which lines of code is taking up the most of that 17 milliseconds, you can't do that without a profiler. Also, DateTime is only accrurate to about 15 miliseconds, to get under than you need to switch to [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx), record one DateTime at the start then use the stopwatch to figure out how much time has elapsed. When you go to write your output do the start time + the TimeSpan from the record of the datapoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String concatenation can be slow, try making a class that holds a DateTime and a string and have pArray hold that instead. Do the conversion to a string later when time is not critical. Also use a Stopwatch to record the duration, DateTime has a minimum resolution of about 15ms.

```
//Declared elsewhere
public class DataPoint
{
    public TimeSpan Time {get; set;}
    public String Message {get; set;}
}


    List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>(pArray.Length); //make the default size the same as pArray so we don't waist time growing the list.

    Stopwatch duration = new Stopwatch();
    DateTime utcStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    duration.Start();
    DateTime endTime = utcStartTime.AddSeconds(recordTime); //Move this out of the loop so it only does the calculation once.
    while (DateTime.UtcNow <= endTime)                       //Run the read-write function for approximately the time specified
    {
        try
        {

            Write("Write.Request");                                 //Requests the data
            Pmeas = Read();                                         //Reads the returned string. String = "ReadError" if no result is found.

            var dataPoint = new DataPoint
                {
                    Time = duration.Elapsed,
                    Message = Pmeas
                };
            dataPoints.Add(dataPoint);                                                     
            Pmeas = "ReadError";                                    //Reset Pmeas to prove in file that Pmeas experienced a read error
        }
        catch (Exception f)                                         //Catch an exception if try fails
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", f);
        }
    }

    //Now that we are out of the time critical section do the slow work of formatting the data.
    foreach(var dataPoint in dataPoints)
    {
        var message = dataPoint.Message;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            message = "ReadError";
        }
        pArray[i] = message + "\t" + (utcStartTime + dataPoint.Time).ToString("%d") + Environment.NewLine;    //Appends the Pmeas of each instance to a string array with a timestamp

        i++;                                            //let i grow so that the array can also grow, plus have a variable already available for being having the string being written into a file (not part of question or code-in-question).
    }
```

However this could be a minimal change, get a profiler ([visual studio comes with one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx), but I like to use [DotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)) and see what actually takes the most time and focus your efforts there.

Comment: I understand and that would make sense. However, if that is the case, could you please give an example of how I should handle the DateTime as an array then?

Comment: Updated answer with example. However I doubt it will save you more than 1 millisecond, I really recommend you get a profile and see where the slow parts are and focus on making them faster.

Comment: I updated it again to use Stopwatch instead of UtcNow. If `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution == false` [it just uses UtcNow internally](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,69c6c3137e12dab4), but if it is true you get a better resolution than UtcNow can provide.

Comment: I won't be able to verify if it helped for a while (due to the nature of the personalized read/write methods, but when it does and if it does help, I will accept your answer and post it as most useful. In the meantime, thank you... I do think it will help a bit.

Comment: The foreach loop is throwing a System.IndexOutOfRangeException, which seems to happen at the pArray. I feel that the cause is the initial creation of string array pArray (what should an empty string array look like?). Aside from that, it does seem a bit quicker than my original code.

Comment: You never showed how `pArray` gets created or what it was used for, so i had to copy what you did. I would likey not have done an array if I was designing this but instead use a `List<string>` and call `myList.Add(someString)` instead of `pArray[i] = someString`.

Comment: I changed the pArray to a normal string since I technically don't need it as an array anymore. However, the time-stamp is not printing out properly (I removed the .toString(%d) because it was not giving me a time stamp); I need the date with accuracy down to microsecond.Can I do that? Additionally, it also seems that the code is going slower than I expected it would (since I changed the loop from a for to a while [before posting this question, which may be the cause of the loss of speed due to time checking]). Is there any other way to speed it up and still keep the time termination the same?

Comment: I forgot to add, the UTC is not displaying in UTC like I want it to. How do I do that? And is the cause of the speed change the loop type(the try-catch method instead of just an infinite for loop)? Any pointers would be helpful. Once I get the code working properly, I'll accept the answer.